# Renaming inserted pictures in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Pictures that are inserted in excel will automatically be named "Picture 1", "Picture 2" and so forth. I'm running a function to put a border around the selected picture. Problem is, if there are two images in the worksheet that is "Picture 1", the function will get confuse and not know which one to put it on but randomly put it on a image which could be incorrect. Is there anyway to change the name box of a image or at least get the selected image?

Here's my code to put border on image:

```
Private Function AddImageBorder(WhichSheet As String)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WhichSheet).Shapes(Selection.Name)
        .Line.Weight = 5
        .Line.Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Function AddImageBorder()
     If TypeName(Selection) = "Picture" Then 'Make sure the object is a picture first
         With Selection.ShapeRange
         .Line.Weight = 5
         .Line.Visible = msoTrue
         End With
      End If

End Function
```

I added a check to make sure the selection is a picture to prevent some errors.

To answer your direct question, you could do:

```
Selection.Name = "NewName"
```

and it will change the name of the picture object.

Comment: Is there a way to rename all the images on the worksheet before adding the imageborder around the selected image?

Comment: Well, I'd start with looping through all of the objects on the sheet, checking if the item is a picture and then renaming it if it is.  Write some code to try to do that, and then if you are having specific trouble with the code, ask a new question.  Also, if this answer resolves the issue in your question, consider marking it as the answer.